# Monospace font too thin and spindly in Chrome

Tags: 12.04, fonts, websites, google-chrome

Could be related to [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/3894) but I couldn't solve the problem with the fixes there.

The issue is especially apparent on websites that use monospace font. For example: http://www.hastebin.com/gosiqosoti.pl is nearly unreadable in Chrome, although I just tried it in Firefox 12 and it looks a bit better.

This is on 12.04 with the latest Chrome stable. Msttcorefonts are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else works, consider editing your `Custom.css`. It should be found at `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User Stylesheets/Custom.css`. (There's a space between `User` and `Stylesheets`! which doesn't matter if you get there via a file manager GUI.)

The file is empty by default unless you've already edited it. You could open it with any text editor and paste in `pre, code, kbd, tt { font-family: "Ubuntu mono" !important; }` or any other monospace font of your choice. But I don't like Courier. It appears fainter than other mono fonts.